# WPF Global style can't be overridden

Tags: wpf, coding-style, textblock

This global style is declared in App.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
     <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Times New Roman"/>
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
</Style>
```

In a window, I've tried to override this locally like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="60" />
</Style>
```

and this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="60" />
</Style>
```

but nothing works. I'm still stuck with the style set up in App.xaml. Does anyone have any idea what could be interfering with this? If I remove that global from App.xaml, I can set whatever I want locally. If I change a value in the global, it's reflected globally, so I don't think there's another global anywhere that's conflicting with it. I searched for `TargetType="TextBlock"` and got nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried your code and it works perfect for me. Where is your window style placed?
I copied it into the Window.Resources and it displays the font with fontsize 60.
If this doesn't work try your code in a new empty project.

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="60" />
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: I have the global in app xaml ad I created a brand new window to test with in the same project. I put the style at the window resources level, grid level and listview level.

Comment: Created a new solution and it worked as expected. I just have no idea what I'm missing that's preventing me from doing the same. Do you know of any project settings or solution settings that make these unoverridable? This has been a problem here before I started and I'd like to come up with a solution outside of making a local style in all 50 screens.

Comment: No, I don't have an idea. But there's a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524864/cant-override-a-global-wpf-style-that-is-set-by-targettype-on-a-single-specific
Perhaps you can find a clue there ..
I'd try to work with merged dictionaries and see if this behavior still occurs

Comment: I've seen that and tried that solution. It's a no-go. Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: This didn't fix my problem, but I think my issue is something other than my code - just gotta figure out what.